# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE site=? WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have a table that I will record an user color.

If user has no color yet, I have no row for him, so I need to insert instead of update.

I try:

```
INSERT INTO cores (`user`,`site`) VALUES ('josh','red')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `site`='red' WHERE `user`='josh' limit 1
```

the `where` is not working... How can I update where user = josh?

Comment: Assuming you have a unique key constraint on `user`, you shouldn't need a where clause. Can you edit the question to include the output of `desc cores;` and `show indexes from cores`?

Comment: my table:  `user` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `site` varchar(6) NOT NULL, UNIQUE KEY `user` (`user`) - user is int, I did a char here just to show better.

Comment: thank you @PatrickLee I remove the where and it works! I thought i need it to work... my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a unique key constraint on the `user` column, this should be sufficient...

```
INSERT INTO cores (`user`, `site`) VALUES ('josh', 'red')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `site` = 'red'
```

Comment: No problem. Sometimes the answer is simpler than we realize.  :)